# While loops for a Python noob

Tags: python

I'm trying to teach my son how to program & I gave him a challenge that I can't do myself.

He has to prompt the user to enter A, B, or C.  Depending on their choice, he'll print some results & other stuff.   While we got this working, I'm trying to do some error handling & check for cases where the input is not A, B, or C.   The code is listed below.  I certainly appreciate any guidance you can offer.

```
print "************************************************************"
print "*                                                          *"
print "*            Welcome to the cinemas                        *"
print "*                                                          *"
print "************************************************************"
print "*                                                          *"
print "*  What movie would you like to see ?                      *"
print "*                                                          *"
print "*  A) Star Wars                                            *"
print "*  B) Bourne Identity                                      *"
print "*  C) The Hunger Games                                     *"
print "*                                                          *"
print "************************************************************"
movie=raw_input()
while(movie!="A","B","C"):
    print "************************************************************"
    print "*                                                          *"
    print "*            Welcome to the cinemas                        *"
    print "*                                                          *"
    print "************************************************************"
    print "*                                                          *"
    print "*  What movie would you like to see ?                      *"
    print "*                                                          *"
    print "*  A) Star Wars                                            *"
    print "*  B) Bourne Identity                                      *"
    print "*  C) The Hunger Games                                     *"
    print "*                                                          *"
    print "************************************************************"
    movie=raw_input()

print "************************************************************"
print "*                                                          *"
print "*  How many tickets would you like ?                       *"
print "*                                                          *"
print "************************************************************"
quantity =input()
cost = 7.5
if movie =="A":
    print "You are seeing Star Wars"
    price = cost*quantity
    print "You owe ", price
elif movie =="B":
    print "You are seeing Bourne Identity"
    price = cost*quantity
    print "You owe ", price
elif movie =="C":
    print "You are seeing The Hunger Games"
    price = cost*quantity
    print "You owe ", price
```

Comment: Python has multi-line string literals (triple quotes, `"""blah"""`) - use them rather than a load of `print` statements! (Better yet, generate those strings automatically - you are changing very little).

Comment: You can check for mismatch using `while(movie not in ["A","B","C"])`.

Comment: Also note that this program has a classic problem of repeating yourself, not only in the strings but in your logic too. Basing your program around a good data structure (a dict of `{"A": "Star Wars", "B": "Bourne Identity", "C": "The Hunger Games"}` would seem appropriate here.

Comment: And as a final note, using `input()` in 2.x is a bad idea! If you want an integer of the user, then use `int(raw_input())` instead!

Comment: @Lattyware - What are the cons of using input() for reading integer in python 2.x? I use it quite frequently.

Comment: @sidi it eval's the input. You're better off using something like `ast.literal_eval(raw_input(...` or when the desired type is known, explicitly use that one

Comment: @sidi Potentially, anything that gets typed in there gets executed. Anything could happen. It's exactly why `input()` was removed from 3.x in that form (it functions like `raw_input()` from 2.x).

Comment: +1 for teaching your kids to program.

Comment: @JonClements `ast.literal_eval()` is great if you expect a stringified Python data structure, but to get an integer when you know it's an integer you want, `int()` is a much better option.

Comment: @Lattyware hence I did put "explicitly use that one" in my comment :)

Comment: @JonClements Missed that one, sorry for jumping on you.

Answer (score 7):

You want to do `while movie not in ("A", "B", "C")`.

`movie != "A", "B", "C"` checks whether `movie` is equal to the three-element tuple `("A", "B", "C")`, which it never will be.

Answer (score 1):

Also, instead of printing each line, you could use a multi-line string:

```
welcometext = """
************************************************************
*                                                          *
*            Welcome to the cinemas                        *
*                                                          *
************************************************************
*                                                          *
*  What movie would you like to see ?                      *
*                                                          *
*  A) Star Wars                                            *
*  B) Bourne Identity                                      *
*  C) The Hunger Games                                     *
*                                                          *
************************************************************"""
```

That way, your program can be pretty compact:

```
print welcometext
movie = raw_input(">>")
while movie.upper() not in ("A","B","C"):
    print welcometext
    movie = raw_input(">>")
```

---

If you'd like to do something a bit more advanced:

```
movies = {
    "A": "Star Wars", 
    "B": "Bourne Identity", 
    "C": "The Hunger Games", 
    "D": "Kill Bill"
}

welcometext = """
************************************************************
*                                                          *
*            Welcome to the cinemas                        *
*                                                          *
************************************************************
*                                                          *
*  What movie would you like to see ?                      *
"""

for letter, movie in movies.items():
    welcometext += "*  {}) {: <52} *\n".format(letter, movie)

# ( <52 is for padding 52 spaces, \n is for the newline )

welcometext += """*                                                          *
************************************************************"""

movieletter = ''
while movieletter.upper() not in movies:
    print welcometext
    movieletter = raw_input(">>")

moviename = movies[movieletter.upper()]
print "You have selected {}!".format()
```

Then later on you could add prices etc to the `movies` dict too. Enjoy!

Comment: I know I suggested it, but one flaw, dicts are unordered, you might want to use `collections.OrderedDict()` or a list of tuples. Also, `while movieletter.upper() not in movies:` would be a good idea. It'd also make more sense just to set `movieletter = None` at the start, not print the `welcometext`, and let the loop deal with it, rather than repeating yourself.

Comment: Also, repeated concatenations are bad, use `str.join()` instead: `"\n".join(["* {}) {:<52} *".format(key, item) for key, item in movies.items()])`

Comment: @Lattyware Ah, I just read the comments. (I'm slow to reply) Great minds :) You're right about the order - if this was important then he could run it through `sorted` (i.e. `letter, movie in sorted(a.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]):`) or list of tuples (as well as an `OrderedDict()`).

Comment: @Lattyware I thought I'd try and keep it as simple as possible - if you use `join` then you really need to understand generator expressions/list comprehension. I don't think this is a particularly performance critical situation :)

Comment: @AlexL, I think plenty of people use `join()` without understanding generator expressions/list comprehension. In particular it's pretty common to use it with a `list` which is what you would be doing using `dict.items()` in Python2

Comment: `movieletter.upper() not in movies.keys()` creates a list and does a linear search in Python2! Just use `movieletter.upper() not in movies` instead.

Comment: @gnibbler Cheers, updated. If you notice anything else I could improve, please feel free to edit my answer :)

Comment: [List comprehensions are not so bad.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of better ways to structure your loop to avoid repetition.

First way is to set the movie to an invalid value, this means the loop will always execute at least once

```
movie = None
while movie not in ("A", "B", "C"):
    print "************************************************************"
    print "*                                                          *"
    print "*            Welcome to the cinemas                        *"
    print "*                                                          *"
    print "************************************************************"
    print "*                                                          *"
    print "*  What movie would you like to see ?                      *"
    print "*                                                          *"
    print "*  A) Star Wars                                            *"
    print "*  B) Bourne Identity                                      *"
    print "*  C) The Hunger Games                                     *"
    print "*                                                          *"
    print "************************************************************"
    movie = raw_input()
```

The second way is to use a `while True:` loop

```
while True:
    print "************************************************************"
    print "*                                                          *"
    print "*            Welcome to the cinemas                        *"
    print "*                                                          *"
    print "************************************************************"
    print "*                                                          *"
    print "*  What movie would you like to see ?                      *"
    print "*                                                          *"
    print "*  A) Star Wars                                            *"
    print "*  B) Bourne Identity                                      *"
    print "*  C) The Hunger Games                                     *"
    print "*                                                          *"
    print "************************************************************"
    movie = raw_input()
    if movie in ("A", "B", "C"):
        break
```

Then you can work on storing the movies in a variable as Alex suggests